# Is it possible to upload separate logos for dark mode and light mode in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams

I wonder if it's possible, or will be possible to upload one logo for light mode, and one logo for dark mode in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Currently, I'm only able to upload one image.

I have marked where we might put a second "Upload new image" button in the screenshot below.
This is only an example.

[image: Current settings page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion! I agree this would be handy but it's not currently on our roadmap.